# Linux : Qt Creator debugger hangs while QQmlApplicationEngine is created

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debugging

I was debugging the qt quick weather example in Qt Creator on Linux, the debugger hangs while the following code is being executed:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine(QUrl("qrc:/weatherapp/qml/main.qml"));
```

The debugger log keeps showing:

> QML Debugger: No application output received in time, trying to connect ...

I am using Qt Creator 3.1.1 on ArchLinux x64.

Comment: Have you created the resource file properly?

Comment: I think so ... it is qt's example, no problem on Mac

Answer (score 13):

This appears to be a bug in Qt (for details see below picture).

As a temporary workaround you can disable QML debugging, which should not have much impact to your debugging experience.
Go to project and build settings and uncheck the QML debugging checkbox at the qmake options, as shown in this picture:

[image: Uncheck QML debugging checkbox]

Do not forget to rebuild afterwards.

I have this issue as well on Arch Linux x86_64. Apparently the QML debugger is waiting for an internal waiting condition to be met.

I have reported [a bug at Qt Project](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-40445).

Comment: This worked for me and should be flagged as the answer.